# JAXB, Netbeans and Interface Insertion Plugin

Tags: jaxb

I can't get my generated classes to implement any interfaces.

This is my xml schema file:

```xml
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"            
        xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/"
        xmlns:ai="http://jaxb.dev.java.net/plugin/if_insertion"
        jxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="ai">


    <xs:element name="header">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:appinfo>
                <ai:interfaces check="1">
                  utility.RuleInterface
                </ai:interfaces>
            </xs:appinfo>
        </xs:annotation>

        <xs:complexType>
            bla bla bla
        </xs:complexType>

    ....
```

I checked the  "Extension" option in the JAXB options and I have added the `xjc-if-ins.jar` to the "Libraries" section of my project Properties.

But the generated Header class doesn't implements the `utility.RuleInterface`.

I can figure out what am I doing wrong... Is it something missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you actually activated the plugin? With an option like `-Xinheritance`?

Here's another plugin you may use:

http://confluence.highsource.org/display/J2B/Inheritance+plugin

Here's a sample project (Ant and Maven):

http://download.java.net/maven/2/org/jvnet/jaxb2_commons/jaxb2-basics-sample-po/0.5.2/

Comment: Here https://jaxb2-commons.dev.java.net/interface-insertion/ it says I have to use the -extension option, which I think is what I do checking the "Extension" option on NetBeans.

Only now I see the -Xifins option... I think now it's going to work, too bad is not possible to use theese xjc options from netbeans

Comment: You also need to turn on this specific plugin using the option like one I specified. -extension is not enough.

Comment: Yes, I figure it out roght now. (I've edited my first comment).

Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Now I got another problem, doing xjc -cp $JAXB_HOME/share/lib/xjc-if-ins.jar -extension -Xifins schema.xsd always returns with "unrecognized parameter -Xifins" error.

Answer (score 1):

Just another note for others with the same problem.
The elements inside the xml schema file should be written in this way:

```
<xs:complexType name="header">
   <xs:annotation>
        <xs:appinfo>
            <ai:interfaces check="0">
              utility.RuleInterface
            </ai:interfaces>
        </xs:appinfo>
    </xs:annotation>          
</xs:complexType>
```

and the you can refer to them:

```
<xs:element name="rule">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="header"  type="header" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                ...
            </xs:sequence>
        <xs:complexType>
```

My problem was that I had declared the header as  `<xs:element name="header">` and than I was referring to the element with `<xs:element ref="header" maxOccurs="unbounded" />` and this approach doesn't seems to work...